# update table in postgresql database through r

Tags: r, postgresql

How do I update data in a postgresql db through R with new data?

I've tried

```
dbGetQuery(con,"UPDATE table SET column1=:1,column2=:2, column3=:3 
              where id=:4", data=Rdata[,c("column1", "column3", "column3","id")])
```

I also tried with the colons replaced with $ but that didn't work either.  I keep getting:

```
Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
unused argument(s)
```

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation to see if placeholders are supported at all? Not every db interface from R does. I know RSQLite does, but I'm pretty sure RODBC does not, and I'm not sure about RPostgreSQL.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured it out using:

```
update <- function(i) {
drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con <- dbConnect(drv, dbname="db_name", host="localhost", port="5432", user="chris", password="password")
txt <- paste("UPDATE data SET column_one=",data$column_one[i],",column_two=",data$column_two[i]," where id=",data$id[i])
dbGetQuery(con, txt)
dbDisconnect(con)
}


registerDoMC()

foreach(i = 1:length(data$column_one), .inorder=FALSE,.packages="RPostgreSQL")%dopar%{
update(i)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At least the RODBC has a specific function **sqlUpdate**:

> sqlUpdate updates the table where the rows already exist. Data frame
>   dat should contain columns
>   with names that map to (some of) the columns in the table

See http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/RODBC.pdf