# R equivalent of SQL update statement

Tags: sql, r

I use the below statement to update to the postgreSQL db using the following statement

```
update users
set col1='setup', 
col2= 232
where username='rod';
```

Can anyone guide how to do similar to using R ?I am not good in R

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: is "users" table a dataframe ?

Comment: Not its the database, i am looking a R code to hit and update in DB table.

Comment: Hmmm...Why are you not using SQL to interact with a DB table?

Comment: requirement is to use R instead instead of direct SQL.

Comment: Hmmm... what requirement is that? How are you connecting to database then? Please explain [more of your entire issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Are you importing the DB table into R then pushing back out? I ask because an R solution has been posted. To directly update you must use language of database (i.e., SQL).

Comment: not not importing any data into r, i found the similar solutions but not able to do
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15099507/update-table-in-postgresql-database-through-r/15179840

Comment: But that solution runs SQL inside R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you didn't provide any data, I've created some here.

```
users <- data.frame(username = c('rod','stewart','happy'), col1 = c(NA_character_,'do','run'), col2 = c(111,23,145), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

To update using base R:

```
users[users$username == 'rod', c('col1','col2')] <- c('setup', 232)
```

If you prefer the more explicit syntax provided by the `data.table` package, you would execute:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(users)
users[username == 'rod', `:=`(col1 = 'setup', col2 = 232)]
```

To update your database through `RPostgreSQL`, you will first need to create Database Connection, and then simply store your query in a string, e.g.

```
con <- dbConnect('PostgreSQL', dbname = <your database name>, user=<user>, password= <password>)
statement <- "update <schema>.users set col1='setup', col2= 232 where username='rod';"
dbGetQuery(con, statement)
dbDisconnect()
```

Note depending upon your PostgreSQL configs, you may need to also set your search path `dbGetQuery(con, 'set search_path = <schema>;')`

I'm more familiar with `RPostgres`, so you may want to double check the syntax and vignettes of the `PostgreSQL` package.

EDIT: Seems like RPostgreSQL prefers `dbGetQuery` to send updates and commands rather than `dbSendQuery`

Comment: Thanks for the response, 
I am looking to directly update the tables to DB using R? not to the local datasets.

Comment: To directly update a DB table you must use language of database (i.e., SQL). Do note: R (general-purpose language) can run SQL (special-purpose language).

Comment: ok 
I found the similar code in other stack 
stackoverflow.com/questions/15099507/… 

But not able to fit to my requirement as state above.? could anyone help

Comment: I would recommend spending some time in https://db.rstudio.com/

Comment: thanks, I am not able to figure out for the update statement.
Anyone can help me on this ? pls..

Comment: @Rod what do you mean by "figure out the update statement"?